# jQuery’s $(document).ready() is it adviceable to use

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please i need some recommendation,  is it adviceable to use jQuery’s `$(document).ready()` because i had a problem loading external page using the load function, googled and stumbled on this [page](http://encosia.com/dont-let-jquerys-document-ready-slow-you-down/)  really want to know if i can run jquery script without `$(document).ready()` need your opinion.. Thank

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.onload vs $(document).ready()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

Comment: This will also be relevant for the time being: **[Dont initalize all the things in jQuery](http://elijahmanor.com/dont-initialize-all-the-things-in-jquery-ready/)**

Answer (score 0):

Since jQuery manipulates the document, using `.ready` makes sure your code runs when the document is ready, i.e. the browser has downloaded the HTML

The `load` will trigger later, when images are loaded, etc.

Also, place your `<script>` tag just before the `<body>` tags ends, this will speed up page loading and contribute to a better user experience.

Comment: Thank you, as much as i want to know

Comment: @MarshallUnduemiJosiah about the above answer: placing your `<script` tag before the `<body>` tag is not as efficient of a method as async/defer. Read: **[Where is the best place to put <script> tags in HTML markup?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24070373/1046690)**

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to look at this is that no one thing is a fix-all for coding. The ready call is great but not for everything your JS does. Also, as others have suggested moving your JS before the body tag can help but not always.

Your question should not be should you use it but rather when to use it.

Comment: Yeah course i found this [link](http://encosia.com/dont-let-jquerys-document-ready-slow-you-down/)  Don’t let jQuery’s $(document).ready() slow you down

Comment: The article is good but again depends on your situation. The live examples are good but if you do not want the user going around trigger click events while the page loads then ready is better. The ajax call I feel is obvious (get the data asap) but also question if it may not impact load time in situations where it hangs or there is a lot to pull in.

Answer (score 0):

$document.ready() is not called in every partial postback. $document.ready() is called only one time i.e. during first time of page loading. if you want to get call back of every partial postback then you have to use pageLoad() method which is the part of scriptmanager generated script means if you want to use pageLoad() method then you need to use asp.net scriptmanager in the page.

Answer (score -1):

JQuery is highly recommended for it cross-browser compatibility, community support, ease of use, and battle-tested.

$(document.ready()) is equivalent to:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    // code goes here

});
```

The window.load function or JQuery load is equivalent to

```
document.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    // code goes here

});
```

The DOMContentLoaded fires when all of the HTML DOM has parsed.
Load fires when all of the HTML DOM has parsed and images have finished loading

To use this method you must ensure you have included the JQuery library and it has loaded beforehand.

Comment: Why the negative mark? LOL .. The people  on this site crack me up